# Perceptron algorithm - is this a typo or did something change in this equation?

Tags: definition

I'm currently reading [*Python Machine Learning*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1783555130) (Amazon link) by Sebastian Raschka.

Here discussing Frank Rosenblatt's perceptron algorithm:

> More formally, we can pose this problem as a binary classification task where we refer to our two classes as $1$ (positive class) and $-1$ (negative class) for simplicity. We can then define an *activation function* $\phi(z)$ that takes a linear combination of certain input values $\mathbf{x}$ and a corresponding weight vector $\mathbf{w}$, where $z$ is the so-called net input ($z = w_{1}x_{1} + \dots + w_{m}x_{m}$):
>   $$
> \mathbf{w} = 
> \begin{bmatrix} 
> w_{1} \\
> \vdots \\
> w_{m}
> \end{bmatrix}, \ 
> \mathbf{x} = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> x_{1} \\
> \vdots \\
> x_{m}
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   Now, if the activation of a particular sample $x^{(i)}$, that is, the output of $\phi(z)$, is greater than a defined threshold $\theta$, we predict class $1$ and class $-1$, otherwise, in the perceptron algorithm, the activation function $\phi(\cdot)$ is a simple *unit step function*, which is sometimes called the *Heaviside step function*:
>   $$
> \phi(z) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 1 && \text{if } z \geq \theta \\
> -1 && \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   For simplicity, we can bring the threshold $\theta$ to the left side of the equation and define a weight-zero as $w_{0} = -\theta$ and $x_{0} = 1$, so that we write $\mathbf{z}$ in a more compact form $z = w_{0}x_{0} + w_{1}x_{1} + \dots + w_{m}x_{m} = \mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{x}$ and $\phi(z) = \begin{cases} 1 && \text{if } z \geq \theta \\ -1 && \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

If we define a weight-zero as the author does and use the form $z = \mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{x}$, shouldn't the activation function become 
$$
\phi(z) = \begin{cases} 1 && \text{if } z \geq 0 \\ -1 && \text{otherwise}\end{cases}?
$$

If not, I don't understand what really happened with the "more compact form", adding a term to $z$ and not doing anything with the activation function.

I checked the book errata and didn't see this which is what is making me unsure if I'm completely missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything. If the initial $z$ is shifted by subtracting $\theta$, so that its new middle point is $\theta$, then the activation function needs to be

$$
\phi(z) = \begin{cases} 1 && \text{if } z \geq 0 \\ -1 && \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks Tim, my apologies for the simple question - I just wanted to be sure and found the wording of this entire part a bit confusing. I'll add it to the errata list.

Comment: @EricHansen no need to apologize.